# How to set the Draggable feedback to be dragged within the parent widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to constraint the Draggable Feedback within the parent widget?

###### Issue Description

The feedback widget while dragging will always be on top of every widget including the **AppBar** and **BottomNavigationBar**.

Here is the [sample](https://dartpad.dev/?id=abe0d8a4ee169ddf69a5a737db4ded6f) of demo that demonstrating the issue.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              const MyWidget(),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                child: Container(width:500, height: 200, color: Colors.red),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Draggable<int>(
      data: 0,
      feedback: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      child: Container(color: Colors.green),
    );
  }
}
```

- **Green** is the Draggable.
- **Blue** is the Draggable Feedback when it drags starting on **Green**
- **Red** and **Green** is the children of the Stack, while **Green** will be at the back of **Red**
- **Yellow** is AppBar and BottomNavBar

###### According to Sample

- Expecting Result: **Blue** will not appear on top of **Red** and **Yellow**
- Actual Result: **Blue** appear on top of **Red** and **Yellow**

Comment: I think it will be easy without Draggable just with  stack[imo].

Comment: Thanks, but the Draggable is a must for my cases. I need it to move the widget around and stay behind the other widget that are higher level to it.